# pass value to method from dynamic input field vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I have a dynamic table with some input field and button in each row. I want to pass each row individual value when i click the button. Can anyone help me how to do it?

HTML:

```
   <tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
      //other Data
      <td><input v-model="item1"></td>
      <td><input v-model="item2"></td></td>
      <td><button @click="doSomething()">send</button></td>
   </tr>
```

javascript:

```
methods: {
    doSomething() {
        //values from each input field
    }
}
```

Comment: You can. Just change 'item1' and 'item2' after clicking button (in the doSomething function. I don't think your question clear.

Comment: @ReşitKörsu i have several table row generated dynamically from server. each row has some input field. I want to get those input fields value when user click the button for each row.

Comment: Then you can create a component for your table row and send data into it so each button in each row could doesSomething according to that rows data.

Comment: didn't help. But got the answer from here. https://jsfiddle.net/h5swdfv5/1/
Thanks for your reply though

Answer (score 1):

Just pass index as a parameter to the function.

```
<button @click="doSomething(index)">send</button>
```

then in the method

```
doSomething(index) {
        //values from each input field
    }
```